# Git Interactive rebase: Squash files to the commit they changed

Tags: git

I have the following commits:

- **`Commit1`** affecting `file1` and `file2`
- **`Commit2`** affecting `file2` and `file3`
- **`Clean up commit`** affecting `file1`, `file2` and `file3` (in this commit I only reformat a few lines)

Is it possible with git rebase to squash the **`Clean up commit`** such that changes to `file1` are applied to **`Commit1`** and changes to `file2` and `file3` are applied to **`Commit2`**? That is changes should be split according to files and then be applied to the last commit the file was changed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this manually. You either have to split up commit3 into commit3 and commit4 and then squash them individually, or you can set commit1 to `edit` in the interactive rebase and commit3 to squash into commit2, then when editing commit1 you apply the changes of commit3 you want to have in and then continue rebasing. The rest should work without problem then, as the changes are applied already.